# sort numpy 2d array by indice of column

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I am using numpy in python. I have a 1D(nx1) array and a 2D(nxm) array.  I used argsort to get a indice of the 1D array. Now I want to use that indice to sort my 2D(nxm) array's colum.

I want to know how to do it?

For example:

```
>>>array1d = np.array([1, 3, 0])
>>>array2d = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

>>>array1d_indice = np.argsort(array1d)
    array([2, 0, 1], dtype=int64)

I want use array1d_indice to sord array2d colum to get:
    [[3, 1, 2],
     [6, 4, 5]]
```

Or anyway easier to achieve this is welcome

Comment: could you explain what your expected output should look like?

Comment: I had changed my description, and It should be clear now. And j__ 's answer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean is that you want the columns sorted based on the vector, then you use argsort on the vector:

```
vi = np.argsort(vector)
```

then to arrange the columns of `array` in the right order,

```
sorted = array[:, tuple(vi)]
```

to get rows, switch around the order of `:` and `tuple(vi)`